# Isometric embedding of 4-element metric spaces into Riemannian manifolds and the curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, curvature

I came across this question [Preferred embedding of finite metric spaces in riemaniann manifolds of given dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42192/preferred-embedding-of-finite-metric-spaces-in-riemaniann-manifolds-of-given-dim). In one of the answers it was stated that it is always possible to isometrically embed 4-element metric space into two different model planes (2-dimensional Riemannian manifolds of constant curvature, or, if the curvature is $-\infty$, an R-tree).

Let $(\{x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3\}, d)$ be a 4-element metric space. I'm interested in whether there is an explicit formula for the curvatures of these model planes reliant solely on the values of the metric $d$. (Equivalently, in terms of the elements of the distance matrix $[d(x_i, x_j)]_{i,j=0}^{3}$ of $X$).